# Collision with two objects

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have many bricks (physics body) on screen (different- different x and y direction) and one ball comes from up direction(y = 0). In this movement, if a ball collides with a brick (from top part) then it is getting some velocity.

Up to here everything works fine, but I want that when ball collides with a brick (from bottom part ) then the ball should behave like an "un-physics" body. Meaning that when it collides from the top part of brick that time, the ball must be a physics body and when it collides with the bottom part in that movement ball must behave like an "un-physics" body.

Is it possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685369/jump-object-on-collision

Answer (score 0):

Just detect the direction the ball is coming (you can use the vertical speed of the ball for example), and if the ball is going upward you set

```
bar.isSensor = true
```

on the object, and then you put it back to false after the ball is not colliding with it anymore or is going down.